# AJAX: responseXML is null in IE 11

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp-classic

An AJAX call using the script below is failing on IE 11. It works on earlier versions of IE - 6 definitely (this is old code), 7, 8, and 9 suspected. It works on Firefox 32.0.1, and probably as far back as 2 (this is very old code).

The script errors at `objXML = req.responseXML.documentElement;` with the error "Unable to get property 'documentElement' of undefined or null reference.".

On debugging, req.responseXML is null, while req.responseText has the expected XML. Searching for this problem, the solutions centre around the response type not being 'text/xml', but the debugger shows that the response type is the correct 'text/xml'.

Why is req.responseXML null?

```
var req;

function loadXMLDoc(url) 
{
    // branch for native XMLHttpRequest object
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.onreadystatechange = processReqChange;
        req.open("GET", url, true);
        req.send(null);
    // branch for IE/Windows ActiveX version
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        if (req) {
            req.onreadystatechange = processReqChange;
            req.open("GET", url, true);
            req.send();
        };
    };
};

function processReqChange() 
{
    // only if req shows "complete"
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        // only if "OK"
        if (req.status == 200) {
            // ...processing statements go here...
            //alert(req.responseText);

            objXML = req.responseXML.documentElement;

            // snip... using response data...

        } else {
            alert("There was a problem retrieving the XML data:\n\n" + req.statusText);
            alert(req.status + "\n\n" + req.responseText);
        };
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the Content-Type header was being set twice. The Classic ASP page which was returning the XML contained the following to set the Content-Type header, belt-and-braces style:

```
Call Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml")
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
```

The summary tab on the network view in IE's F12 Developer Tools shows the 'Type' as 'text/xml'. The details tab shows two 'Content-Type' entries in 'Response headers'. IE 11 does not like this. Removing the first call to set the Content-Type and leaving just `Response.ContentType = "text/xml"` has resolved the issue.